# How to use data stream from bash with subprocess in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, data-stream

I am trying to call a process in linux bash using data stream signal '<' to use a file as input to an application.

However, this application do not receives its input from the file.
I am using this:

```
#the application do not receives data stream from file

command = './grid < /home/felipe/Documents/proteins/grid.in'.split(' ')

p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it does not work such as os.system(), that did what I want to do with subprocess:

```
#works
command = './grid < /home/felipe/Documents/proteins/grid.in'.split(' ')

os.system(command)
```

How can I use data stream signal '<' with subprocess module to get input to an application?

Comment: No. `<`  is a *shell* operator. In subprocess you should open the file yourself and pass it to `Popen` as `stdin`.

Comment: @iBug thanks a lot. There is a more detailed answer below that shows a example of how to do it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to use Python as a shell wrapper, you would have to launch your (sub)process with `shell=True`. But since you're already using Python, you may want to rely on Python more and on shell less, you could do the following:

```
with open('/home/felipe/Documents/proteins/grid.in') as in_file:
    p = subprocess.Popen('./grid', stdin=in_file)
```

This opens your input file as `in_file` and feeds it into standard input of `./grid` just like shell redirection would do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that is the best way to do what I need. I will try it soon to the result. This application runs in an sever that I can't access right now. Soon I will let you know if it worked to me. :)

Comment: It really work to me. Once more, thanks for your help.